# PAYTM Session expired due to inactivityYou double-clicked on a button

Tags: php, api, paytm

I am using paytm API with these detial

```
define('PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT', 'TEST'); 
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', '1epzsxP7694JVXXX');
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', 'JOBMAS04239965714XXX'); 
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'WEB_STAGING'); 

$PAYTM_DOMAIN = "pguat.paytm.com";
if (PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD') {
    $PAYTM_DOMAIN = 'secure.paytm.in';
}
```

and it is working well but when I login with phone no: 7777777777 and OTP– 489871 after login when i press pay now i get the error :

An Oops! moment
Payment failed due to any of these reasons:

```
Session expired due to inactivity
You double-clicked on a button
Our system encountered an obstacle
```

> ```
> Clear cookies & temporary internet files of the browser
> Check payment status with your bank to avoid double payment
> Launch a new browser & start from the beginning
> Still unable to transact? visit us at paytm.com/care
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the below parameter

```
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'WEBSTAGING');
```